# DIV: Completely rendered indicator event 

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call a **javascript** function when a `div` is fully rendered. But, I am not aware of the right event to use.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put a script inline within the document that calls your function or executes. Just put it logically where it should be rendered.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div><h1>Wait for it!</h1></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write("<h2>Js process</h2>");
            alert("Stopping document process");
        </script>
        <div><h3>Done!</h3></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this example the script is executed when the first div is fully rendered. Logically it is the next block item to execute, so as elaborated in other answers there is no event needed.

Answer (score 1):

No events, just create  a callback function, after the writing of html is finished, call your callback routine.

```
function x ( html, callback) {
     divElement.innerHTML = html;
     callback();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need something like this:

```
<!-- This is the Div to be rendered: -->
<div> 

 <script>
         /* This script is executed when all div is rendered!!*/

 </script>

</div>
```